# PHP Mysql update table using form will not update

Tags: php, mysql

Ok so I am trying to get my form to update my table to edit a contact but for some reason with 0 errors it just won't update and I just can not figure out why as it all looks good to me.

Here is the edit contact script

```
// Connect to database
$dbc = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");
if (!$dbc) 
    die("Could not connect: " . mysql_error());

// Select database
$db_select = mysql_select_db( "contactmanager", $dbc );
if (!$db_select)
    die("Could not select DB: " . mysql_error());


// Build update function for form
if(isset($_POST['update'])){
    mysql_query("UPDATE contacts SET Name='$_POST[name]', Address='$_POST[address]', Phone='$_POST[phone]', Mobile='$_POST[mobile]', Email='$_POST[email]' WHERE ContactID = $contactID") or trigger_error(mysql_error());

    echo 'Update has been pushed and fucntion has run';


} else {
    echo 'Update has not been pushed.';
}

// initialize form control values
$name = '';
$address = '';
$phone = '';
$mobile = '';
$email = '';

// Get ID of contact selected for editing
$contactID = $_GET['id'];

// build sql select statement
$query = "SELECT * FROM contacts WHERE ContactID = '$contactID'";

// Run sql statement against database
$result = mysql_query($query, $dbc);

if ($result) {

    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

    $name = $row["Name"];
    $address = $row["Address"];
    $phone = $row["Phone"];
    $mobile = $row["Mobile"];
    $email = $row["Email"];
}
else { 
    // If there is an error display message
    echo '<p><b class="error">Error with $rst: ' . mysql_error($dbc) . '</b></p>';
}

?>


    <form name="editcontact" method="post" action="edit-contact.php" id="editcontact">
        <fieldset>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="name">Name</label></dt>
                <dd><input name="name" type="text" value="<?php echo $name; ?>" size="33" maxlength="50" tabindex="1" /></dd>
            </dl>   
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="address">Address</label></dt>
                <dd><textarea name="address" cols="33" rows="5" tabindex="2"><?php echo $address; ?></textarea></dd>
            </dl>   
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="phone">Phone</label></dt>
                <dd><input name="phone" value="<?php echo $phone; ?>" type="text" size="33" maxlength="50" tabindex="3" /></dd>
            </dl>   
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="mobile">Mobile</label></dt>
                <dd><input name="mobile" value="<?php echo $mobile; ?>" type="text" size="33" maxlength="50" tabindex="4" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><label for="Email">Email</label></dt>
                <dd><input name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" type="text" size="33" maxlength="50" tabindex="5" /></dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt></dt>
                <dd><input type="submit" value="Update" name="update" tabindex="6" style="margin-left:7.3%;" /></dd>
                <dd><a href="list-contacts.php" alt="Contacts List"><p style="margin-left:7.3%;">Back to contacts list</p></a></dd>
            </dl>

        </fieldset>
    </form>

<?php


?>
```

Comment: [`Lovely()`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/)

Comment: You left out a parameter in `$dbc = mysql_connect("localhost", "root");` which should read as `$dbc = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password_xxx");` --- *Plus,* everything outside of the `if(isset($_POST['update'])){...}` conditional statement will be ignored upon submitting, which is where your `$contactID = $_GET['id'];` is located; amongst other things.

Comment: you are missing the ' signs in your $_POSTs for example $_POST[name] should be $_POST['name']

Comment: The tutorial I followed stated that the single quotes in $_POST[] are emitted because they would cause problems because the $_POST its self is in quotes.  DB connect is fine there is no password so it's omitted.  So how would you recommend it be typed because I can't put '$_POST['name']'

Comment: I see what you mean about the ID being set out side of the function and is probably the main cause of the problem.

Comment: I'm next to 100% sure of it. @RiCHiE

Comment: You can declare your variable first `$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);` etc., then use `SET Name='$name',` etc. @RiCHiE yet using [**mysqli with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) is better, or [**PDO**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Thanks good to know I got it to work now the ID was the problem:     Is this what you mean by using prepared statements:                                                                      if(isset($_POST['update'])){
 
 $Upname = $_POST['name'];
 $Upaddress = $_POST['address'];
 $Upphone = $_POST['phone'];
 $upmobile = $_POST['mobile'];
 $Upemail = $_POST['email'];
 $Upid = $_POST['id'];
 
 
 mysql_query("UPDATE contacts SET Name='$Upname', Address='$Upaddress', Phone='$Upphone', Mobile='$upmobile', Email='$Upemail' WHERE ContactID = $Upid") or trigger_error(mysql_error());
 
}

Comment: You're welcome and am glad to hear it. No, those are not prepared statements. See this link => http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php <= @RiCHiE and this tutorial http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5:-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452

Comment: You should also change `$Upname = $_POST['name'];` to `$Upname = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);` for the time being, and do the rest for the others, following the same convention. @RiCHiE Least, that will give you some form of security.

Comment: Thanks for all the help I will have a look at that tutorial :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything outside of the `if(isset($_POST['update'])){...}` conditional statement will be ignored upon submitting, which is where your `$contactID = $_GET['id'];` is presently located.

Place it within the conditional statement.

```
<?php
...

if(isset($_POST['update'])){

    // $contactID = $_GET['id']; // original
    $contactID = intval($_GET['id']); // recommended for (INT) type
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); // etc.

...

}
```

---

Sidenote: Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/). Use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/mysqli) functions. (which I recommend you use and with [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO**](http://php.net/pdo))

You should change:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
```

to:

```
$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
```

for the time being, and do the rest for the others, following the same convention.

Then do `SET Name='$name'` etc., and do the same for the others. That will give you some security until you get familiar with prepared statements, or PDO.

---

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Here are a few tutorials on prepared statements that you can study and try:

- [**Tutorial one**](http://webdevtuts.co.uk/simple-mysqli-tutorial/#more-41)
- [**Tutorial two**](http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/PHP-5:-MySQLi-Prepared-Statements/41452)
- [**Tutorial three**](http://www.phpmysqlitutorials.com/2011/04/16/mysqli-whats-the-difference-between-standard-queries-and-prepared-statements/)

Here are a few tutorials on PDO:

- [**PDO tutorial one**](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html)
- [**PDO tutorial two**](http://crewow.com/PHP-PDO-to-Connect-MySQL-Database.php)
- [**PDO tutorial three**](http://www.w3resource.com/php/pdo/php-pdo.php)

Comment: Thanks, I completely forgot about escaping the strings. I will recode it as such :)

Answer (score 1):

The id or contactID never makes it through the form and into the processing portion of the code. Just before the final set of `<dl>` tags in your form, you can add a hidden input to pass the ID through the form and into $_POST array:

```
<dl>
    <dt></dt>
    <dd><input name="contactID" value="<?php echo $contactID; ?>" type="hidden" /> </dd>
</dl>
```

Then in the processing portion, you can add a line to grab the value again:

```
if(isset($_POST['update'])){

    $id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['contactID']);
    $name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $address = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['address']);
    $phone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['phone']);
    $mobile = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['[mobile']);
    $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);

    mysql_query("UPDATE contacts SET Name='$name', Address='$address', Phone='$phone', Mobile='$mobile', Email='$email' WHERE ContactID = $id") or trigger_error(mysql_error());

    echo 'Update has been pushed and function has run';

} else {//as before...
```

Also, take a good hard look at the comment about using mysqli from @Fred-ii-